# blkid doesn't doesn't print the device name on CentOS

Tags: centos, block-device, uuid, lsblk, libblkid

I am running a container with CentOS:

```
docker run -it centos bash
```

I first check for its Label or UUID:

```
[root@3271c071fe0a /]# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-1032-aws root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 nvme_core.io_timeout=4294967295
```

Then I tried to use the Label (`cloudimg-rootfs`) and convert it to device name so I used `blkid` but it doesn't print anything:

```
[root@3271c071fe0a /]# blkid -L="cloudimg-rootfs"
[root@3271c071fe0a /]#
```

I was expecting to get `/dev/xvda1` because I checked it with `lsblk`:

```
[root@3271c071fe0a /]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1     7:1    0 96.6M  1 loop
loop2     7:2    0 28.1M  1 loop
loop3     7:3    0 97.1M  1 loop
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
`-xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /etc/hosts
```

Why it doesn't print it?
I tried with `=`:
[image]

And without:
[image]

Comment: I would say the syntax is wrong, there should not be an `=` sign: `-L "something"`.

Comment: I tried also with `=` and it doesn't work - see edit with picture

Comment: Did you try *without* the `=`?

Comment: Yes, updated the answer with print screen

Comment: 1) Does the output of `blkid` without arguments include, in any place, the string you are searching for? 2) `lsblk -o +LABEL` may help you check if a volume labeled `cloudimg-rootfs` is actually known to the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't used `blkid` for this task because it is unreliable. If you check `man blkid` under the DESCRIPTION section you'll find this passage (emphasis mine):

> It is recommended to use lsblk(8) command to get information about block devices, or lsblk --fs to get an overview of filesystems, or findmnt(8)  to  search  in  already  mounted filesystems.

> lsblk(8)  provides more information, better control on output formatting, easy to use in scripts and it does not require root permissions to get actual information.  ***blkid reads information directly from devices and for non-root users it returns cached unverified information.***  blkid is mostly designed for system services and to test libblkid functionality.